# How to set Content-Security-Policy to allow botframework scripts in web.config file

Tags: web-config, botframework, sharepoint-2013, content-security-policy, direct-line-botframework

I'm adding a Direcline bot into my SharePoint page, I created a content editor webpart and added a HTML file in it, inside the html file I used the following code to call the bot,

```
         window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
        {
           directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
              token: 'tokenid'
           }),

           styleOptions,
           userID:emailid  ,
           username:user  ,
           locale: 'en-US',
           userAvatarInitials: 'iniital'
        },
        document.getElementById('webchat')
     );
     document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
```

While loading the bot,  i'm getting the following console error in chrome and the bot is not working.

> **Refused to connect to** 'wss://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/7BqkaBZaNQIKKjPc2VBAOw-h/stream?watermark=-&t=ew0KICAiYWxnIjogIlJTMjU2IiwNCiAgImtpZCI6ICJBT08tZXhGd2puR3lDTEJhOTgwVkxOME1tUTgiLA0KICAieDV0IjogIkFPTy1leEZ3am5HeUNMQmE5ODBWTE4wTW1ROCIsDQogICJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIg0KfQ.ew0KICAiYm90IjogIkNBU19OTFBfQm90IiwNCiAgInNpdGUiOiAiOVBrZGsxZFpfOU0iLA0KICAiY29udiI6ICI3QnFrYUJaYU5RSUtLalBjMlZCQU93LWgiLA0KICAibmJmIjogMTU3NzY4NzQ3NSwNCiAgImV4cCI6IDE1Nzc2ODc1MzUsDQogICJpc3MiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9kaXJlY3RsaW5lLmJvdGZyYW1ld29yay5jb20vIiwNCiAgImF1ZCI6ICJodHRwczovL2RpcmVjdGxpbmUuYm90ZnJhbWV3b3JrLmNvbS8iDQp9.PwUk4yQgpXZ_ohnTUAZzfnvG5NQTteaLvX5iDDPbC6nFrs_S7pICngcldf_R8ujPDFBQISSXNc3O7fF5ndX3Qqk8SHPl1jM2yOV0tkqxKu-C-4OvTr2sDW_k7vmGpvNQQrbiAQvVrimNydrr3a6B2coQlvNes1CdZopsi01wnanDNmXErJBkQnCQ0-yQvkSSP7PiiC8eQewUsVT6onCsvBpwWj-CoZ6TBmWZdYUcGtZRx1WkqyZwKvRbKtyqvr_S7jBfZlL51DozYBEQ4_C0bt2R2p-7MTlE6egUi9ZTSTNklVlIFBqw7_hdWR92NLsWZqWewGUb2RvapYaTpWObuA' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Because in my web.config file I do have this CSP header.

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

When I remove this header, I'm able to run the bot, and its working. but I don't want to remove this header in my web.config file, I want to explicitly mention this botframework URL so that it allows the bot to run.

**So please help me how to explicitly set this header to allow the required scripts to run the bot.**

Comment: Either add `wss:` to your `default-src` directive, or else add a `connect-src wss:` directive+value.

Comment: thank you so much for replying,  I've added wss: inside my default-src and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for commenting the answer, by adding the wss: the issue is fixed.

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src https: data: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```